Dynamic input field
i have a internal website that has a input field which is very dynamic beside that input field there is a add button. so how does this work if i add some value in input field and click add the input field converts the value in node and the value is displayed below the input field. however i want to apply a tampermonkey script that would automatically put the value and click on add button .the problem is whenever i try to put value using console the value is displayed inside the input field but it is not accepted when i click on add button .and there is onchange function on that input field .not sure what to do. and how to create the tampermonkey script
const xpath = "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/main/div/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/form/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/input";

const inputField = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;

if (inputField) {
  
    inputField.focus();

  
    const inputText = "Hello World";

    // Simulate typing each character
    inputText.split("").forEach((char, index) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            // Create keyboard events
            const keydownEvent = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", { key: char, bubbles: true });
            const keypressEvent = new KeyboardEvent("keypress", { key: char, bubbles: true });
            const inputEvent = new Event("input", { bubble`your text`s: true });
            const keyupEvent = new KeyboardEvent("keyup", { key: char, bubbles: true });

            // Dispatch events in sequence
            inputField.dispatchEvent(keydownEvent);
            inputField.dispatchEvent(keypressEvent);
            inputField.value += char; // Update the value
            inputField.dispatchEvent(inputEvent);
            inputField.dispatchEvent(keyupEvent);
        }, index * 200); // Delay between each character
    });
} else {
    console.log("Input field not found.");
}

